# $http.post send Authorization Header

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to pass an Authorization Header with a $http.post call to a .NET Web API service.

If I use this :

```
$http.post(urls.getEmployeeInfo,
        {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers:{ 'Authorization':  'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password)}
        }
    );
```

The Authorization header does not get sent to my service.

The following works :

```
$http({
            url: urls.getEmployeeInfo,
            method: "POST",
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password)
            }
        });
```

Why doesn't $http.post send the Authorization Header ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$http` takes only one argument: `config` [[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)]

`$http.post` takes three arguments: `url`, `data`, (and an optional) `config` [[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)]

So if you want to pass configuration options, such as headers, you need to send them as the third argument, rather than the second:

```
$http.post(urls.getEmployeeInfo, postData,
    {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers:{ 'Authorization':  'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password)}
    }
);
```