# How to pass Authorization Token in Header Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, authorization

In my controller I am trying to call my API but I am unable to pass Autherization token.

I have created a config var and passing my token in it but getting following response:

**900902Missing CredentialsRequired OAuth credentials not provided. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"**

** JS Code **

```
 app.controller("AuthenticationController", function($scope, API_URL, vcRecaptchaService, $http) {

       var config = {
         headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer 00000-e5673-346756f-8676-f7567561a'
         }
       };
       $scope.verifyRecaptcha = function() {

         if (vcRecaptchaService.getResponse() === "") {
           alert("User did not resolve the recaptcha")
         } else {
           var post_data = {
             'g-recaptcha-response': vcRecaptchaService.getResponse()
           }
           $http.post('https:1.1.1.1/abc/vdc/verify', config, post_data).success(function(response) {

               if (response.success === true) {
                 alert("Successfully resolved the recaptcha.");
               } else {
                 alert("User verification failed");
               }
             })
             .error(function(error) {
               alert("Error Occured while resolving recaptcha.");
               console.log(error);
             })
         }
       }
```

Comment: Have you tried `$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN ';` refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425107/angularjs-set-a-authorization-header

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249440/http-post-send-authorization-header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you've switched the position of the payload and the header

should be 
`http.post(url, data, config)` instead of `http.post(url, config, data)`

link to [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#shortcut-methods)

I'd recommend to put all the logic inside an http interceptor, so the auth header will be appended to each request.

Comment: Thanks bro. Banging head with walls.

Answer (score 1):

To pass `authorization` in header, include `$httpProvider` in your angular module.

And the following `function` as factory :

```
function authInterceptor($localStorage) {

        return {
            request: function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if ($localStorage.token) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer' + 
                    $localStorage.token;
                }
                return config;
            },
        };

    }
```

And `call` this factory in your module. So it will add Authorization header in all your `$http` requests automatically. And you don't need to add authorization header in each request.

Comment: I dont want to use local storage

Comment: OK. you can use another way instead of local storage.